# Caret / Cursor is not [really] take focus after .focus() using JQuery

Tags: jquery, focus, caret, setfocus

i'm trying to set the focus to the next input box after the user select a value from the autocomplete drop down (using jquery).

so the code look like this:

> function showElement(elementName) {
>            $(elementName).show('blind', onElementDisplay(elementName));
>        }
>
> ```
>  function onElementDisplay(elementName) {
>      $(elementName).focus();
>  }
> ```

so i would expect to see the cursor/caret blinking on the element that was displayed at the end of the function, hence the user can start type in, however, it doesn't happen.

anything i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is a callback (type Function). You are passing it the return of `onElementDisplay`, which would be `undefined`.

Add an anonymous function wrapper.

```
function showElement(elementName) { 
    $(elementName).show('blind', function(){
        onElementDisplay(elementName); 
    });
}

function onElementDisplay(elementName) {
    $(elementName).focus();
}
```

Comment: unfortunetly, that not the problem. even with this example, the caret is not being placed in the next input box.

Comment: Well, is `elementName` a proper selector? If it is an `id` it must begin with `#`. If there is another problem with your code I will need to see more to fix it. Example html, example calling `showElement`.